# wxWidgets: Get some unique machine ID to use in validation/registration

Tags: c++, security, wxwidgets, registration, uniqueidentifier

Does wx provide a handy way to get anything like this in a platform-independent way? I don't think  C++ libs themselves provide anything.
I don't have a definite idea what should be used for the unique ID... MAC address is common but what else could be used?

If we were doing it Windows-specific, is there a way to get the actual Windows indentifier/serial #?

Answer (score 0):

Mac addresses can be cloned.

Personally, under windows, I use WMI to obtain the Hard disk serial number.  That works well :)

Comment: Can be maliciously? Or might happen under normal usage? The former is probably not too big a deal in this case.

Comment: Maliciously though it can be handy when you have a network card set as your ISP interface.  Clone the mac address on a diff card to maintain access with minimal troubles.  Its VERY easy to do.

Comment: HDD serial number can be changed even easier.

Comment: A HDD can crash. What will happen to your customer ? Will he have to buy a new licence ? If so, how to distinguish people that really crashed their HDD and people that just want a free licence ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no predefined class inside the wxWidgets framework, that offers an UID generation. The framework offers mostly the platform independent definition of GUI objects. If you look inside the [class list](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_classesbycat.html#classesbycat) offered by wxWidgets you will find no classes, that will allow you to read a MAC address or a HDD serial number. You will have to write your own method to determine a unique identifier. There seem to be solutions for [unix like systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328936/getting-a-unique-id-from-a-unix-like-system) and for [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99880/generating-a-unique-machine-id).