# Secure Jar file

Tags: java, spring

I have a jar file project build from Spring framework with hibernate but I don't want other pc execute my jar file. I want my jar file work only the pc that I want to run. Anyone have any idea ?

Comment: can you please add more details?

Comment: Simply take a encrypted key from properties and decrypt in your program before start. Use the key only in your System you want. Also Obfuscate the code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to prevent a program from running on another computer. Anyone determined and skilled enough could bypass protections.

However if you're not worried about this you can check for certain computer-specific settings such as the [MAC address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644722/generating-id-unique-to-a-particular-computer) and kill the program if they're not what you expect them to be. This approach would be obvious to anyone with a decompiler though. To make this more complex and harder to bypass you can encrypt your jar file with a key generated from the MAC address and have it decrypted at runtime. This would make it much harder to execute unless the person who runs the program knows your information.