# Obtain a unique hardware identifier in C++ in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, hash, hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reliable way of generating unique hardware ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842116/reliable-way-of-generating-unique-hardware-id)

I would like to retrieve an unique hardware identifier for a single machine in C++. Any suggestions? I need this software working in Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8. I just need a few system calls to retrieve MAC address, hard disk serial number, or something like this.

Comment: What are you going to use it for? That will change what values are okay to use. A MAC address will be unique in normal use, but it can easily be changed to something that is not unique if the user desires.

Comment: Here's a simplified version of the CodeProject article, that uses C# and WMI to basically compile the HUID using machine's hardware specs. It should be fairly easy to translate it into C: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28678/Generating-Unique-Key-Finger-Print-for-a-Computer?msg=4156672#xx4156672xx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encrypt any value with the machine's [DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) key and use the encrypted value as your ID.

**Note:** I copied my [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13053731/591064) to the question that this one duplicates.

Comment: DPAPI will use PBKDF2 encryption method that uses random "salt", which will produce a resulting cipher text with random values every time you generate it. So unless you specify how to make PBKDF2 not use random "salt" (I'm guessing, via CryptProtectData API) I don't see how your suggestion would work? More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/network/networkinformation/article.php/c5451/Three-ways-to-get-your-MAC-address.html) is a great article on how to get your mac address using C++. You could use one of those three methods of getting your MAC address, after which you could use some sort of encryption (eh sha256) on these MAC address -- that is of course, only if you want these MAC address to be hidden while you store them.

Comment: It might be a usecase-related matter, but MAC addres SHOULD not be used to identify machines. I see this answer on many similar posts, but since MAC addresses can be easily altered it is not a reliable way to take...