# Why Window Object Passed to Function

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html code

```
<a href="javascript:update(this)">Val1</a>

<a href="javascript:update(this)">Val2</a>
```

And the function

```
function update(obj) {
     alert(obj); // I expect to get a tag object but I am getting Window Object
    //do something

}
```

Now I would expect to get object referring to a tag, but I get Window Object. Can some one tell me why object referring to a tag is not passed

Comment: **window**.location.href

Comment: This is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842116/reliable-way-of-generating-unique-hardware-id The question there is "how." The question *here* is "why."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can some one tell me why object referring to a tag is not passed

Because this isn't an event attribute, it's a URL. The code in URLs using the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol is run as global code, with `this` referring to the global object, just like code in `script` elements (that don't use `"use strict"`) is.

If you were using an event attribute, like `onclick`, then the code would be run as though it were in a function at global scope with `this` set to the element and an in-scope `event` variable referring to the current event.

Comment: Yes this makes complete sense.

Answer (score 1):

You are visiting a `javascript:` scheme URI and not firing an event in the context of an Element object.

```
<a href="sensible_fallback.html" onclick="return update(this)">Val1</a>

function update(element) {
    alert(element);
    return false;
}
```

… but this is 2014, so don't use intrinsic event attributes.

```
<a href="sensible_fallback.html" id="foo">Val1</a>

function update(event) {
    alert(this);
    event.preventDefault();
}

document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('click', update);
```

… and if you don't have a sensible fallback, then use a button, not a link.

Comment: +1, but I did expect you to recommend anonymous functions. addeventlistener('click', function(..){..})

Comment: I prefer separate function declarations. They are easier to read (since they aren't buried in the middle of another function call) and their name shows up on the stack in debuggers (and while you can have named function expressions, IIRC they leak memory in old-IE).