# How to form unique identifier?

Tags: c#

I developed a software with `C#` which will be running in windows machines and I want to use something unique for licensing my software so I decided to the `Processor ID` of the computer but when I did some tests it turned out that lots of unbranded computers has the exact same `Processor ID` so I decided to use a combination of the following:

`Processor ID` - `HDD Serial Number / model` - `Motherboard ID`

but again it turned out that lots of unbranded computers has exact same `Processor ID` - `HDD Serial Number / model` - `Motherboard ID`  even `MachineGuid` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography` is exactly the same. I do not want to use `MAC address` because some machines do not have MAC address.

I had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310328/best-way-to-get-a-unique-identifier-in-c-sharp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474940/unique-computer-id) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101772/win32-processoris-processorid-unique-for-all-computers)  but it did not help.

Anyone knows how can I find a unique identifier on the computer?

Comment: What about the `MachineGuid` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography`? Is a windows specific identifier enough?

Comment: This is a bad idea and very rarely done today because it has lots of problems. Almost all software today is licensed to a person/organization based on their identity rather than characteristics of their physical machines.

Comment: -Marco, thanks for mentioning that, yes even the MachineGuid is exactly same

Comment: Mac Address could be a choice

Comment: @HansKilian most subscriptions are a combination of person and machine based (netflis/apple licensed to person and specific number of machines) so there should be some way of tracking

Comment: I have not done it, but would think this would be typical to how browsers manage cookie, on user request you would leave a unique key on the user machine and record this in your app/license server. On your app startup (or every once a week), you can check in if the installation has proper license and if any users has installed it more copies then allowed.

Comment: Tangential discussion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20676008/where-can-i-store-and-manage-application-license-information/20676247#20676247. MAC address is extremely problematic (because there might be more than one NIC and it might be turned on/off). A combination of Computer (manufacturer, model) Motherboard (manufacturer, model, serial number), BIOS (manufacturer, serial number), CPU ID and `MachineGuid` should provide a fairly unique ID. Of course it won't help with VMs (but there isn't much you can do to extract a truly unique ID from a VM unless you create and store one yourself

Comment: The main point is...for what you want to use this ID? To uniquely identify a client (for example to _validate_ a license? To detect when multiple users contacts a server using the same license from different computers? To detect when a machine specific license is reused in a new installation (even by the same user)? Each problem has a slightly different solution (even not considering VMs...)

Comment: Adriano Repetti -  I want To uniquely identify a client ( to validate a license)