# How to retrieve domain computer's sid

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to retrieve the domain sid for the local machine (not the machine sid). I need to be able to retrieve it without incurring network traffic to the AD server.

I found these links:

http://microsoft.public.platformsdk.security.narkive.com/y8UW72ww/how-to-get-the-domain-sid-of-the-domain-the-computer-belongs-to

[How can I retrieve a Windows Computer's SID using WMI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133399/how-can-i-retrieve-a-windows-computers-sid-using-wmi)

And tried to GetComputerName followed by using IADsNameTranslate to convert to a sid, but when setting the name to translate I get error: 0x80072116 "Could not find the name or insufficient right to see name".

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: have you tested `get-sid "CLIENT$"` as explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3135006/1300910)?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Yes, that works, but how do you achieve the same when using the Win32 api from C++?

Comment: Why not just execute the PS function? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c

Comment: You can use WMI from C++.  (I don't know how, but I know that you can.  There are probably existing questions.)