# How get uuid of a device/partition in linux programatically?

Tags: c++, c, linux, uuid

I am very much new to Linux programming.

My questions are:

- Is there any way to read the UUID of a device or partition in Linux programmatically?
- Is there any C/C++ API for user-space applications?

I found some commands `sudo vol_id --uuid /dev/sda1`, `sudo blkid` and `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/`. But all of them are commands which need to run in a terminal. But I need to achieve this from a C/C++ program.

Can some one help me with this problem. (FYI: I need to read UUID of the root filesystem ("/") where Linux has been installed.)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could use `getfsfile("/")` as answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/344656/2508277)

Answer (score 2):

The general approach would be:

- find out what device your / is on by parsing `/etc/mtab` for example

  go through the `/dev/disks/by-uuid` directory (using `opendir/readdir/closedir`) and find which one points to that device.

See the `readlink` function for getting the target of a symbolic link. You'll find plenty of code examples for parsing text files on this site or with your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Since `blkid` already does it, you could also just see how it works and pilfer the solution, **if** you abide by util-linux's license (GPLv2).

Comment: You only need to abide by the license if you pilfer the actual code; copyright protects implementations but not ideas. Otherwise, you couldn't even use the `opendir/readdir/closedir` idea because there's a `ls` implementation doing that.