# Portable UUID on Linux

Tags: linux, uuid

On Windows and MacOSX it is trivial to retrieve some kind of UUID per machine:

On Windows (regedit):

```
"Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\MachineGuid"
```

On MacOSX

```
$ ioreg -rd1 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | grep IOPlatformUUID
```

However on Linux this is [much more complex](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/ids.html). So far I have found the following:

1. On dbus based system:

   $ cat /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
2. On x86 based system (requires **root power**):

   $ sudo cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/product_uuid
3. On PowerPC based system:

   $ cat /proc/device-tree/serial-number

What's really odd, is that UUID for the main board on x86-based arch is restricted to root user, but can be accessed using regular user via hal (`$ lshal | grep 'system\.hardware\.serial'`). While at the same time, all disk UUIDs can be accessed (`$ ls /dev/disk/by-uuid/`) and *serial number* can be accessed from any user on PowerPC-based arch.

**So is there any portable UUID I can use on Linux ?** *dbus* may or may not be installed, I need to read this value from a *non-root* user, and it needs to remains the *same* across reboot (`/proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id` is therefore not an option).

Comment: [Is there a UUID type of value in Linux that can uniquely identify an instance of a VM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8722050/608639), [Best way to get machine id on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10152762/608639), [Generate consistent machine unique ID](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/144812), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `systemd` is now installed on most Linux distributions these days, therefore i can rely on `/etc/machine-id` being present and readable from a regular user.

Comment: Yes `systemd` uses it himself - look at `hostnamectl` output.