# Uniquely Identifying an OSX Machine

Tags: swift, macos, uuid

I want to Identify a Mac based on Hardware ID.I have seen this

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn1103/_index.html

It gives mainly 2 approaches

## 1 -Using S/N: But it seems this might not be supported in future Machines

## 2 -Using MAC ID: I don't know if this is reliable

Could you please suggest the best way and provide me some sample code in SWIFT to start with.Almost all examples are in Objective C.
I'm new to SWIFT as well.

Comment: Swift code for obtaining the serial number is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35486613/1187415, and Swift  code for obtaining the MAC address of the (built-in) Ethernet interface is here https://stackoverflow.com/q/31835418/1187415.

Comment: Macs have also a Hardware UUID

Comment: @vadian Is this approach reliable ... Can you point me in some direction or may be a sample code :)

Comment: It's the same as getting the serial number but passing the key `IOPlatformUUID`. Consider that the tech note is from 2006 / 2011. The approach is reliable.

Comment: @vadian Which is the most reliable approach? Can you Please provide me some example..

Comment: @MartinR Thanks... Which is the most reliable approach?

Comment: You can do this in Terminal if that helps... `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType` It gives you a serial number and a hardware UUID.

Comment: Once again it's the same code as getting the serial number but passing `kIOPlatformUUIDKey`rather than `kIOPlatformSerialNumberKey`

Comment: @techno You can use the serial number approach from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35486613/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus Is this reliable and will this work on all versions of OSX? Please advice..

Comment: @techno I haven't tested it on different macOS versions but nothing stops you from doing so. It looks reliable considering that all you need is to import Foundation.

Comment: You can also make it non optional and a bit shorter using guard case let and returning an empty string in case of an unlikely failure `var serialNumber: String {
    guard case let platformExpert = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice") ), platformExpert > 0, let serialNumber = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(platformExpert, kIOPlatformSerialNumberKey as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0).takeUnretainedValue() as? String else {
        return ""
    }
    IOObjectRelease(platformExpert)
    return serialNumber
}`

Comment: @LeoDabus: The purpose of optionals is that you *don't* have to return magic values (like empty strings) in the case of a failure :)

Comment: @MartinR is it possible for a macOS machine to do not have a Serial Number?

Comment: @vadian: I wonder why TN 1103 does not mention the IOPlatformUUID, do you have an idea?

Comment: @MartinR He can also just throw a fatalError() instead of returning an empty string in this case `var serialNumber: String {
    guard case let platformExpert = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice") ), platformExpert > 0, let serialNumber = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(platformExpert, kIOPlatformSerialNumberKey as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0).takeUnretainedValue() as? String else {
        fatalError("Serial Number not found")
    }
    IOObjectRelease(platformExpert)
    return serialNumber
}`

Comment: @Leo I don't know if the calls can fail. But yes, either you *assume* that they succeed, or you return an optional and let the caller decide. – But even Apple's same code at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn1103/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10002943-CH1-TNTAG3 check the success of the calls and *might* return NULL.

Comment: @MartinR My guess: The tech note is pretty old and talks about Panther (10.3) and Tiger (10.4). `kIOPlatformUUIDKey` has been introduced in Leopard (10.5)

Comment: @vadian: Good point! – And perfectly documented https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/kioplatformuuidkey: "No overview available" :)

Comment: @vadian You can't run Swift based apps on OSX earlier than 10.9 anyways

Comment: @LeoDabus * _g_ * Indeed. Another advantage for the hardware UUID.

Comment: Using kIOPlatformUUIDKey in above code gives the same result as calling `gethostuuid()`, and the man page of that function states: *"Be aware that the hardware identifiers that gethostuuid() uses to generate the UUID can themselves be modified."*

Comment: @MartinR so also from the link you posted **It is possible for a system to lose its serial number so that it will no longer appear either in System Profiler or the I/O Registry. Repairing a system by swapping hardware components is one reason this can happen. Apple does not document the specific details of how a machine can lose its serial number. Once the serial number has been lost there is no means to restore it to the machine.

Apple does not guarantee that all future systems will have a software-readable serial number.**

Comment: @MartinR Which one do you think it is the recommended approach ?

Comment: @LeoDabus: I don't know. None of the approaches listed in TN 1103 is guaranteed to be stable.

Comment: @vadian never mind I did manage to create a method here

Comment: @LeoDabus You're welcome.

Comment: @LeoDabus Can you please share your solution?