# Is there any Value in PHP which is unique for each system

Tags: php

In PHP, is there any way to get a value that is unique to the system it is running on?

Ideally, I would like it to be a sort of random string that stays the same on the system that is running on, but is different on other systems.

I need one that I don't have to store in an separate file/DB and is easily available on each script.

Comment: define "system". Are you looking for an UUID?

Comment: Any value string/number which is unique for each system.

Comment: PHP doesn't have a built in UUID generator that I know about, but [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) used in conjunction with unique hostnames may do the job for you.

Comment: But as the manual cautions, uniqid() is not high-entropy and not to be used for any crypto purpose. Instead, http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php

Comment: If you are looking for unique value for user computer, than it's not related to PHP, because PHP parameters comes from server OS/system.

Comment: `uniqid()` is not a constant value it returns different values each time.

Comment: I would personally look up the UUID of the system like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328936/getting-a-unique-id-from-a-unix-like-system

Answer (score 1):

Create your own random value (with uniqid for example) and put it to environment variable. For [user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-do-i-set-a-user-environment-variable-permanently-not-session), [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) or [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#env). Or just define it in your php file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes -

Ultimately, you want `gethostname()`

And if you do :

```
echo md5($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'].gethostname());
```

Then you will have a unique string that pertains only to that server

But, there are plenty of other values that will be unique-ish

Try :

```
<?php 

print_r($_SERVER); 

?>
```

And you should find several values that are like what you are looking for.

Such as:

```
 [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => nginx/1.4.6

 [SERVER_ADDR] => 123.456.789.909
```

Then, there are also some predefined constants that may hold what you want -

```
<?php

print_r(get_defined_constants()); 


?>
```

Which has things like:

```
[PHP_VERSION] => 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5
[PHP_MAJOR_VERSION] => 5
[PHP_MINOR_VERSION] => 5
[PHP_RELEASE_VERSION] => 9
[PHP_EXTRA_VERSION] => -1ubuntu4.5
[PHP_VERSION_ID] => 50509
```

And while these values will be identical on servers that are running the same software stack -- it is often not likely that these values will match perfectly...
However, your best bet for unique ID would be the IP address + the host name-

Comment: Well this could be the perfect solution for any real website but I am looking for an solution which should work on local server too and also should be unpredictable such as `gethostname()`.

Answer (score -4):

You could generate the `uniqid()` append hostname, then hash it with something like `md5` or `sha-256`