# Solaris and Unix unique identifier

Tags: unix, solaris, uniqueidentifier

I'm planning to create multiple virtual machines from a Solaris template. I need to remove any unique identifiers post-cloning of the VM (Hardware and Software). So far I've found:

```
hostid
```

..and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328936/getting-a-unique-id-from-a-unix-like-system) talks about the UUID of the root filesystem.

Are there any other identifiers for Unix/Solaris that need changing?

Thanks

Comment: [`ssh` host keys](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5166/sshd-1m/index.html#Files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at removing /etc/sysidcfg
once removed, when the system boots it will prompt for identification information, unless provided via the network, or a populated sysidcfg.

the sysidcfg manpage from oracle may be of assistance to you?
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5174/6mbb98ujq/index.html