# How to get serial number or UUID of a PC on Linux?

Tags: linux, uuid, uniqueidentifier

In windows OS, we can get Serial Number in BIOS by querying WMI to identify a unique machine. 
Do we have any way to do this in Linux OS in C++? 
Do we have any API to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the "UUID" of a PC? There is no such thing, AFAIK. There are things like MAC addresses for network interface controllers or UUIDs for file systems, but there is no unique identifier for entire PCs.

Comment: What about Linux running in some virtual machine? Your question is unclear (since in general PCs don't have serial numbers). BTW, a clever enough developer could patch the Linux kernel (since it is free software) to fake some UUID good for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a unique id from a unix-like system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/328936/608639). Also see Posix [`gethostid(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostid.3.html) and [`machine-id (5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/machine-id.5.html) man page. It looks like `gethostid` is backed by `/etc/hostid` on systems with glibc.

Comment: UUID means user unique ID, I am pretty sure, this is not what are you asking for :), for all other, please clarify the question with edit of the post, thanks

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx: I think in the context of the question UUID stands for Universally unique identifier, not user unique id.

Comment: @Veverke yes, but in general its simply some kind of unique ID, the specific meaning is related to specific usage

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Terminal. For example, in Ubuntu, you can launch this command:

```
sudo dmidecode –type system
```

The required info are in the `System Information` section.

P.S. you must have root privileges

Comment: You can also look at /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid

Comment: Yes, in /sys/class/dmi/id/ you could retrieve single useful info, like product_uuid, product_sku, product_serial, etc.